# Download PHPWord File with laravel livewire without save file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, phpword

i'm trying to download a file generated with PHP Word, but i'll generate around of 10 000 files daily, i need to download file with laravel livewire without save the file in storage, someone could help me?

This is my code:

```
public function downloadDoc()
    {
        $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
        
        $section = $phpWord->addSection();
        $html = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, nl2br(strip_tags($this->result, '<strong>')));
        $text = $section->addText("Que onda chavo");

        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
        $name = time().rand();
        try {
            $objWriter->save(storage_path('document'.$name.'.docx'));
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
        return response()->download(storage_path('document'.$name.'.docx'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key solution here is you should use

```
$objWriter->save("php://output");
```

To echo data to php output and then use Response::stream to output as file

```
public function downloadDoc()
{
    $callback = function()
    {
        $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    
        $section = $phpWord->addSection();
        $html = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, nl2br(strip_tags($this->result, '<strong>')));
        $text = $section->addText("Que onda chavo");

        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
        
        try {
            $objWriter->save("php://output");
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
    };
    
    $name = time().rand();
    
    $file = 'document'.$name.'.docx';
    $headers = array(
        "Content-type" => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=".$file,
        "Pragma" => "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control" => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
        "Expires" => "0"
    );
    
    
    return Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers)->send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Livewire should handle any file download that Laravel would.

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/file-downloads#introduction

```
return response()->streamDownload(function () {
    echo 'CSV Contents...';
}, 'export.csv');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#streamed-downloads

Though streamedDownloads are supposed to be string based